# GNOME hotspot sleeps after sometime

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, broadcom, hot-spot

I tried to create a hotspot from *Gnome GUI* and from [Create ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) both are working but whenever laptop on battery gnome hotspot become unconscious( means hotspot is active but can't take connections and the connected device are removed) after 3-4 seconds and when a laptop on power hotspot will alive for 25-30 seconds after that it becomes unconscious too.

**Note**: If we are using the Internet continuously(downloading something) from created Hotspot then it will alive util we left device on rest(not using internet) for 25-30 sec(as i mentioned above).

```
unknown@unknown:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
wlan1     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BTOof"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 58:D5:6E:D0:C4:38   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2747  Invalid misc:35547   Missed beacon:0
```

**Hope you noticed that power management is also off.**

Here I'm using everything latest.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **GNOME** | *3.38.3* |
| **Internet device** | *Ralink RT5372* |
| **Hotspot device** | *BCM4322*, Driver: *b43* |